# JFrame minimized dock icon setting similar to mac apps

Tags: java, macos, swing

When a MAC app is minimized it will be minimized to the dock with a new icon(combination of active window and the icon). How can i implement it into a JFrame. I have tried it with,

```
setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(Eg.class.getResource("/resource/img.png")));
```

Help me please.

Comment: i used system look and feel ("select look and feel" in eclipse is ticked on "System")

Comment: @Nizil that is actually the default L&F on Mac OS X...